# GitHub action to build dockerfile on specific branch change

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to create a GitHub action that will rebuild a dockerfile if a change is made to specific `branch` then pushed to `main`. If I remove the `branch/specific` the GitHub action works.

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ], [ branch/specific/** ]
    paths:
      - '**.sh'
```

have also tried:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - 'branch/specific/**'
    paths:
      - '**.sh'
```